# Como crear un instalador para mac desde visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms, macos

Tengo un programita hecho con `windows form` en `Visual Studio 2019` con `c#` y una base de datos `sql server 2014` creo el instalador con `Setup Installer Projects`, que me da un `.exe` ¿se puede hacer un instalador de ese mismo programa para Mac desde visual studio? ¿O debo ocupar otro programa?

Comment: winforms es solo para windows...

Comment: @gbianchi y como reutilizar ese código para macOS?

Comment: tendrias que usar MAUI (que es nuevo, no tiene nada que ver con winforms). y es net 6 (ademas de tener que cambiar la UI, deberias por ahi cambiar muchos de los paquetes). Tendrias el mismo problema si fuera para linux....

Comment: @gbianchi y seria igual de escritorio?

Comment: lee al respecto. si es maui es para lo que quieras...